# Convert 2d array into parent-child structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to take an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [model_id] => 1
        [member_id] => 25
        [comment_text] => Me feel good about this
        [created_on] => 2020-12-26 10:02:58.205335
        [comment_id] => 89dab457-cff2-4ae4-9251-48e4f9c7bc63
        [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
        [model_name] => STL_friend
        [member_name] => zeus_the_god
        [comment_parent] => d0e92ab1-5867-4ca4-952e-8ca4424982ea
        [original_date] => 2020-12-25 15:09:28.403925
        [cmt_names] =>
        [row_likes] => 0
        [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:09:28.403925
    )
    
    [1] => Array
    (
        [model_id] => 1
        [member_id] => 25
        [comment_text] => Oh YES YES YES
        [created_on] => 2020-12-25 15:09:28.403925
        [comment_id] => d0e92ab1-5867-4ca4-952e-8ca4424982ea
        [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
        [model_name] => STL_friend
        [member_name] => zeus_the_god
        [comment_parent] =>
        [original_date] =>
        [cmt_names] => dean.manner
        [row_likes] => 1
        [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:09:28.403925
    )
    
    [2] => Array
    (
        [model_id] => 1
        [member_id] => 25
        [comment_text] => @spiffy_kid  - We can do that
        [created_on] => 2020-12-25 15:17:53.572503
        [comment_id] => 395cac7c-ea28-491b-92c7-3d0b8444a78f
        [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
        [model_name] => STL_friend
        [member_name] => zeus_the_god
        [comment_parent] => 7b89e577-1e8f-4c24-bb83-48aa0f9e3a25
        [original_date] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
        [cmt_names] =>
        [row_likes] => 0
        [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
    )
    
    [3] => Array
    (
        [model_id] => 1
        [member_id] => 17
        [comment_text] => Let's do this fast and quick
        [created_on] => 2020-12-25 15:16:59.806941
        [comment_id] => 42c5a5f0-ac3e-4c28-b633-37e014d27977
        [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
        [model_name] => STL_friend
        [member_name] => spiffy_friend
        [comment_parent] => 7b89e577-1e8f-4c24-bb83-48aa0f9e3a25
        [original_date] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
        [cmt_names] =>
        [row_likes] => 0
        [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
    )
    
    [4] => Array
    (
        [model_id] => 1
        [member_id] => 18
        [comment_text] => How you doing?
        [created_on] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
        [comment_id] => 7b89e577-1e8f-4c24-bb83-48aa0f9e3a25
        [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
        [model_name] => STL_friend
        [member_name] => dean.manner
        [comment_parent] =>
        [original_date] =>
        [cmt_names] =>
        [row_likes] => 0
        [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
    )

)
```

and make it look like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [model_id] => 1
        [member_id] => 25
        [comment_text] => Oh YES YES YES
        [created_on] => 2020-12-25 15:09:28.403925
        [comment_id] => d0e92ab1-5867-4ca4-952e-8ca4424982ea
        [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
        [model_name] => STL_friend
        [member_name] => zeus_the_god
        [comment_parent] =>
        [original_date] =>
        [cmt_names] => dean.manner
        [row_likes] => 1
        [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:09:28.403925
        [cmt_reply] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [model_id] => 1
                [member_id] => 25
                [comment_text] => Me feel good about this
                [created_on] => 2020-12-26 10:02:58.205335
                [comment_id] => 89dab457-cff2-4ae4-9251-48e4f9c7bc63
                [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
                [model_name] => STL_friend
                [member_name] => zeus_the_god
                [comment_parent] => d0e92ab1-5867-4ca4-952e-8ca4424982ea
                [original_date] => 2020-12-25 15:09:28.403925
                [cmt_names] =>
                [row_likes] => 0
                [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:09:28.403925
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [model_id] => 1
        [member_id] => 18
        [comment_text] => How you doing?
        [created_on] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
        [comment_id] => 7b89e577-1e8f-4c24-bb83-48aa0f9e3a25
        [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
        [model_name] => STL_friend
        [member_name] => dean.manner
        [comment_parent] =>
        [original_date] =>
        [cmt_names] =>
        [row_likes] => 0
        [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
        [cmt_reply] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [model_id] => 1
                [member_id] => 17
                [comment_text] => Let\\\'s do this fast and quick
                [created_on] => 2020-12-25 15:16:59.806941
                [comment_id] => 42c5a5f0-ac3e-4c28-b633-37e014d27977
                [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
                [model_name] => STL_friend
                [member_name] => spiffy_friend
                [comment_parent] => 7b89e577-1e8f-4c24-bb83-48aa0f9e3a25
                [original_date] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
                [cmt_names] =>
                [row_likes] => 0
                [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
            )
                [1] => Array (
                [model_id] => 1
                [member_id] => 25
                [comment_text] => @spiffy_kid - We can do that
                [created_on] => 2020-12-25 15:17:53.572503
                [comment_id] => 395cac7c-ea28-491b-92c7-3d0b8444a78f
                [event_id] => 3112f8ff-6119-48c4-810c-594585b5dc63
                [model_name] => STL_friend
                [member_name] => zeus_the_god
                [comment_parent] => 7b89e577-1e8f-4c24-bb83-48aa0f9e3a25
                [original_date] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
                [cmt_names] =>
                [row_likes] => 0
                [date_check] => 2020-12-25 15:12:15.54293
            )
        )
    )
)
```

But I can't get it there.  I'm very close, but it just isn't there.
The function needs to identify all array elements where the value of `[comment_parent]` === the value of `[comment_id]` in another element. If they match, then element with `[comment_parent]` becomes a subarray of the one with the matching `[comment_id]`.

Attempt one:

```
foreach ($qrtn as $key => $val){
    $cmt = $val['comment_id'];
    $prt = $val['comment_parent'];
    foreach ($qrtn as $keyed => $value) {
        $cmt2 = $value['comment_id'];
        $prt2 = $value['comment_parent'];
        echo "$cmt === $prt2\n";
        if ($cmt === $prt2) {
            $qrtn[$key]['subcmt'-1] = $value;
            unset($qrtn[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

attempt two:

```
$arrCmts = array_diff_assoc(array_column($qrtn, 'comment_id'), array_column($qrtn, 'comment_parent'));
$arrCmt1 = [];
    array_walk($arrCmts, function ($itemed, $keyed) use (&$qrtn, &$arrCmt1) {
    foreach ($qrtn as $key1 => $val) {
        $cmtItm2 = $val['comment_id'];
        $prtItm2 = $val['comment_parent'];
        if ($prtItm2 === $itemed) {
            $qrtn[$key1-1]['subcmts'] = $val;
            unset($qrtn[$key1]);
        }
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
$arrInt = array_diff_assoc(array_column($qrtn, 'comment_id'), array_column($qrtn, 'comment_parent'));
$arrCmts = array_diff_assoc(array_column($qrtn, 'comment_parent'), array_column($qrtn, 'comment_id'));
$arrCpr4 = array_intersect($arrInt, $arrCmts);
$arrCpr2 = array_diff($arrInt, $arrCmts);
   foreach ($qrtn as $key1 => $val) {

    $cmtItm2 = $val['comment_id'];
    $prtItm2 = $val['comment_parent'];

    $arCmt2 = array_search($prtItm2, $arrCpr4);
    if (in_array($prtItm2, $arrCpr4)) {
        $arCmt3 = array_search($cmtItm2, $arrCpr2);
        $qrtn[$arCmt2]['subcmts'][$ss] = $val;
        $ss++;
        unset($qrtn[$arCmt3]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your entries into parent-child relationships in a single pass over the input array by declaring references to each parent entry and pushing all children into its respective parent reference.  Any child entry encountered can then be removed from the input array because it will be moved to its rightful place within the parent.

The beauty of this approach is that it doesn't matter if a parent is encountered before its first child or if the first child is encountered before its parent.  The references make sure that everything moves to the right place.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/B7D6c))

```
foreach ($array as $i => &$row) {
    if ($row['comment_parent']) {  // is a child
        $commentsRef[$row['comment_parent']][] =& $row; // push child into reference
        unset($array[$i]);  // remove child from (first level) of the original array
    } else {  // is a parent
        $commentsRef[$row['comment_id']] ??= [];  // ensure there is an array to reference
        $row['cmt_reply'] =& $commentsRef[$row['comment_id']];  // assign reference
    }
}
var_export($array);
```